# Where are the default node modules stored

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, file, directory

I was wondering where the default node.js modules are stored on a mac, such as fs, stream, path, etc. I tried looking into my /usr folder, but I couldn't find anything. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal command to find the root location (where global modules are installed) is:

```
npm root -g
```

In a Mac, it should be `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `npm list -g` this command will list globally installed packages with their path.